# Filter JSON with null POST query return in API

Tags: python, api, graphql

I have a python script that connects to a graphql API and sends a POST, so returning me a JSON this API belongs to a kanban, where it has cards arranged by its workflow, my problem and I have 152 cards, and this query is me returning 143, because some cards are not assigned to people, only exist in the workflow.
This generates an index error for the so-called `'assignees': row ['assignees'][0]['fullname']`, I put `try/except` with index filter, and made him add this line again to the dictionary giving the full name `Null`, however this seems to have failed because the total number of cards is 153 and not 143. Is there a more elegant way to do this data engineering?

**py:**

```
    dataDict = {}
    for row in ModelData:

        try:

            dataDict.update(
            { row["identifier"]: 
            {'title' : row["title"], 
            'description' : row["description"], 
            'assignees' : row['assignees'][0]['fullname'], 
            'createdAt' : row["createdAt"]}})

        except IndexError as e:

            dataDict.update(
            { row["identifier"]:
            {'title' : row["title"], 
            'description' : row["description"], 
            'assignees' : "", 
            'createdAt' : row["createdAt"]}})
            pass
```

**data example:**

```
{
"identifier": "x5g",
"title": "card name",
"description": "hello world",
"assignees": {"fullname": "John"},
"createdAt": "2020-04-04"
}
```

**What generates error::**

```
{
"identifier": "x6g",
"title": "card name 2",
"description": "hello world",
"assignees": {"fullname": ""},
"createdAt": "2020-04-04"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with an if statement:

```
dataDict.update(
  { 
    row["identifier"]: {
      'title' : row["title"], 
      'description' : row["description"], 
      'assignees' : row['assignees'][0]['fullname'] if 'assignees' in row else "", 
      'createdAt' : row["createdAt"]
    }
  })

I dont know what the data you get looks like without the assignees but I think you get the Idea.
```

Comment: But I return the index error after removing the `try/except` - [FAILED] Caused by: list index out of range

Comment: Would you like to see a model of the data?

Comment: Than you probably have to write 
`if len(row['assignees']) > 0 else ""`

Comment: In javascript it is usually used as follows for this approach `row['assignees'][0]['fullname'] and row['assignees'] || " "`, however in python I did not find a German form `try/except`

Comment: So it is still not working in Python?
Can you then give some example data?

Comment: Ok, in this case you just have to write `'assignees' : row['assignees']['fullname']`
The index [0] is only necessary in lists (arrays). In dicts(Objects) you can access the values by the key, in this case 'fullname'